# Groovy com oauth2

Tags: oauth2, groovy

Estamos desenvolvimento uma chamada a um Web Service de envio de SMS que utiliza autenticação oauth2. Esse desenvolvimento está sendo realizado em groovy. Buscamos em diversos fóruns como elaborar a chamada, passando os parâmetros e como receber a resposta do web service. Estamos com dúvida se estamos desenvolvendo da maneira correta, já que não temos informações claras sobre os steps do código. Em anexo temos o que o serviço pode responder, abaixo o resultado de uma chamada via Linux.

```
 $ curl URL_PARA_PEGAR_O_TOKEN -d 
"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=USUARIO&client_secret=SENHA"
Retorno: 
{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"TOKEN_RETORNADO","expires_in":7200}

 $ curl URL_DO_SERVICO \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_RETORNADO" \
   -X POST \
  -d 'JSON A SER ENVIADO'
```

Poderiam nos ajudar a estruturar o código, criticando possíveis erros ou sugerindo alguma inserção de algum ponto faltante?

```
    @Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.6-SNAPSHOT' )
    ])
    import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
    import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
    import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC
    import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON
    import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST



    //def client = new RESTClient ( 'http://localhost:8080' )
    //def site = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://localhost:8080' )
    //site.auth.basic 'my-client-with-secret-2', 'secret-2'
    //site.auth.basic 'dmac', 'foo'
    //site.auth.basic 'MC101', 'MC101'


    def credentials = [
      client_id:"<client-id>", 
      client_secret:"<client-secret>",
      site:"https://ms.foo.com.br
    ]


    def accessToken
    site.post(path: '/oauth2/token',
                body: [grant_type:'client_credentials',client_id='client_id',client_secret='client-secret'],
                requestContentType: URLENC ) { resp, reader ->

        accessToken = reader['access_token']

    }

    //println("Access Token: ${accessToken}")
    site.auth.basic "",""
    //accessToken = "8cab2bd9-d55b-4cb9-bf11-73545917bc57"
    site.get(path: '/ssp/api/1/person',
            contentType: JSON,
            query: ["limit": 1],
            headers: ['Authorization': "Bearer ${accessToken}"]) { resp, reader ->

        System.out << "Person response: " << reader
        println()

    }
```

o YAML está abaixo:

```
        swagger: '2.0'
        info:
          description: TST 
          version: 1.0.0
          title: APIs - TST
        host: ms.foo.com.br
        tags:
          - name: Send TST object
            description: 'TST'
        schemes:
          - https
        paths:
          '/tst/templates/V1/{id}/message':
            post:
              tags:
                - Sendo obj
              summary: Send obj 
              description: 'TST '
              consumes:
                - application/json
              produces:
                - application/json
              parameters:
                - name: id
                  in: path
                  description: "Object ID"
                  required: true
                  type: string
                - name: body
                  in: body
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/definitions/TSTTemplateMessage'
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: OK
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/definitions/TSTTemplateResponseMessage'
                '401':
                  description: NOK 1
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/definitions/Unauthorized'
                '450':
                  description: NOK 2
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
                '550':
                  description: NOK 3
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
              security:
                - sms_templates_message: []
        securityDefinitions:
          sms_templates_message:
            type: oauth2
            tokenUrl: 'https://ms.foo.com.br/tst/templates/V1/id/message/oauth2/token'
            flow: application
            scopes: {}
        definitions:
          SMSTemplateMessage:
            type: object
            description: Entity that represents the object
            properties:
              id:
                type: string
                description: Object Identifier
                example: "212db47-711-7589-4a56-123"
              numberCell:
                type: string
                description: Attribute 1
                example: "551111111111"
              templateParameters:
                type: array
                description: Set of values
                items:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    name:
                      type: string
                    value:
                      type: string
                example:
                  - name: name
                    value: "John"
                  - name: date
                    value: "12/12/2012"
                  - name: plan
                    value: "tst plan"
                  - name: order
                    value: "1234"
              trackingId:
                type: string
                description: aaaaa
                example: "9012909"
            required:
              - numberCell
          SMSGeneralMessage:
            type: object
            description: aaaaa
            properties:
              from:
                type: string
                description: aaaaa
                example: "54321"
              to:
                type: string
                description: aaa
                example: "55434344111"
              textMessage:
                type: string
                description: aaaa
                example: "Jaaaa"
              requestDate:
                type: string
                description: "aaa"
                example: "20/04/2012 00:30:00"
            required:
              - from
              - to
              - textMessage
          SMSTemplateResponseMessage:
            type: object
            description: aaaa
            properties:
              templateMessage:
                $ref: '#/definitions/SMSTemplateMessage'
              sentMessage:
                $ref: '#/definitions/SMSGeneralMessage'
          Error:
            type: object
            properties:
              message:
                type: string
              detail:
                type: string
              providerDetail:
                $ref: '#/definitions/ProviderDetail'
          ProviderDetail:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
              code:
                type: string
              message:
                type: string
          Unauthorized:
            type: object
            properties:
              error_description:
                type: string
                example: The access token is invalid or has expired
              error:
                type: string
                example: invalid_token
        externalDocs:
          description: Find out more about Swagger
          url: 'http://swagger.io'
```

Felipe

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando 'client_credentials', que é o flow usado apenas por clientes (aplicações) OAuth, geralmente para fazer autenticação entre backends, não por usuários. Se é isto mesmo que você quer fazer, o seu código parece estar correto, mas tome cuidado com a senha do cliente, nao inclua a senha na sua aplicação, por exemplo.

Se você quer autorizar usuários, você precisa usar o chamado "code flow" que requer vários steps ao invés de apenas um (que é a razão OAuth é capaz de autenticar e autorizar usuários de maneira mais segura do que se a senha fosse enviada diretamente). Este flow geralmente requer o uso de um browser, e a autenticação é feita por um site diferente daquele que requer autorização (que é representado pelo cliente OAuth).

Eu recomendo entender bem como OAuth 2.0 funciona. Este site pode ajudar bastante (em inglês): https://nordicapis.com/8-types-of-oauth-flows-and-powers/

Também é melhor usar uma library para evitar algum erro usando um cliente HTTP diretamente, como você está fazendo.

Você pode escolher uma entre várias opções listadas neste site: https://oauth.net/code/java/

Uma opção boa é provavelmente a library da Google: https://github.com/googleapis/google-oauth-java-client